# how to make a row responsive in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello i'm try to write this text " choose a one to modify the number " and the word "to modify " is with a different style text . my problem here is that the text is not responsive that mean there is not a return to next line if the phone has a small screen
how can i fix it and make this text in the center ?

```
Row(
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            "Choose a one",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
                              color: Color(0xFF000000),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "to modify",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
                              color: Color(0xFFFF9E4F),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "the number",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 17,
                              fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
                              color: Color(0xFF000000),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
```

Comment: why you use row in first place? use rich text instead. here the link https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using rich text, it will be like the following

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: "Choose a one",
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 17,
      fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
      color: Color(0xFF000000),
      ),
    children: const <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'to modify',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
        color: Color(0xFFFF9E4F),
      ),
      TextSpan(text: ' the number',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontFamily: 'SFProRegular',
        color: Color(0xFF000000),
      ),
     ),
    ],
  ),
)
```